# VS Code Extension HTML Injection Grammar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I'm trying to make everything inside a comment inside `TODO(...)` to act like javascript. It just doesn't work. There is neither any output.

package.json

```json
{
    "contributes": {
        "grammars": [
            {
                "path": "./syntaxes/injection.json",
                "scopeName": "todo-comment.injection",
                "injectTo": [
                    "text.html.basic"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

syntaxes/injection.json

```json
{
    "scopeName": "todo-comment.injection",
    "injectionSelector": "L:comment.block",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#todo-keyword"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "todo-keyword": {
            "match": "TODO\\((.+?)\\)",
            "name": "keyword.todo",
            "captures": {
                "0": {
                    "patterns": [
                        {
                            "include": "source.js"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```